# Passing pipes into shell commands via Java application

Tags: java, windows, shell

I need to find out how much memory a certain process (java.exe) is using from within a java webapp.

I have tried the following:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist /v | find \"java.exe\"");
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader errInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
```

But this returns the following:

ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '|'.
Type "TASKLIST /?" for usage.

I know this is because a pipe is a shell feature and is parsed by Java before being passed to the shell.

I have also tried:

```
String[] procString = {
    "cmd",
    "/c",
    "tasklist /v | find \"java.exe\""
};
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(procString);
```

But this doesn't return anything to either BufferedReader.

Is there a way to get the correct output into the webapp?

Comment: Always use the `exec(String[] cmdarray)` form of exec when you have arguments. `.exec` is not a command parser and will almost always get things wrong if you have even a mildly complex command.

Answer (score 0):

The stdInput and errInput streams must be periodically consumed before the exec () function returns. The exec () function blocks whenever the buffer is full. That is, the command through the exec () function does not proceed when there is no space to write to the buffer. To solve this problem, read the buffer after each buffer is full in another thread.

It is a mistake that is easy for a person who gets into a Java program. If you have defined a stream, it must be consumed (via the read function)

Comment: I'm reading from the buffer using `while ((output = stdInput.readLine()) != null) { System.out.println(output); }` right after I initialise the buffer. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Is the buffer-consuming code running separately from the thread on which the exec () method is executed?

Comment: No, it's on the same thread. Should it be on a different one?
So what you're saying here is that I am getting the output as expected, but it's too large for the buffer to handle?

Comment: yes you should. exec() will be blocked and you never reach the code doing consuming

Comment: The standard output of the process performed by exec () is buffered by the BufferedReader you are using. When this buffer is full, the process you are doing through exec () stops and waits (blocks) until you free the buffer. In other words, you need to periodically read the buffer and empty the buffer. It is your freedom to use or discard the data you read.

Comment: However, if you perform the emptying of the buffer after the exec () code, you will not be able to access the code because it blocks exec (), and the program seems to stop. Therefore, the act of flushing buffers must be done concurrently on different threads.